# Evaluate $\int{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the following integral, but seems these 2 methods led to different answers. I think one of the methods must be incorrect. But why doesn't one of them work?

Evaluate $\int{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}\ dx$

My friend evaluated this way:

> First let $x=a\cos{\theta}$, so
>    $a^2-x^2=a^2(1-\cos^2\theta)=a^2\sin^2{\theta}$ $$ \int{\sqrt{a^2 -
>  x^2}}\ dx = -\int{a\sin{\theta}}\ d(a\cos{\theta}) =
>  -\int{a^2\sin^2{\theta}}\ d\theta=-a^2\int{\frac{1-\cos{2\theta}}{2}}\ d\theta
>  $$ $$ = -\frac{a^2}{2}\int(1-\cos{2\theta})\ d\theta =
>  -\frac{a^2}{2}\left(\theta - \frac{\sin{2\theta}}{2}\right) $$ $$ = \frac{a^2}{2}\left(-\cos^{-1}{\frac{x}{a}}+\frac{{x}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a^2}\right)
>  $$

However I've done this way:

> First let $x=a\sin{\theta}$, so
>    $a^2-x^2=a^2(1-\sin^2\theta)=a^2\cos^2{\theta}$ $$ \int{\sqrt{a^2 -
>  x^2}}\ dx = \int{a\cos{\theta}}\ d(a\sin{\theta}) =
>  \int{a^2\cos^2{\theta}}\ d\theta=a^2\int{\frac{1+\cos{2\theta}}{2}}\ d\theta
>  $$ $$ = \frac{a^2}{2}\int(1+\cos{2\theta})\ d\theta =
>  \frac{a^2}{2}(\theta + \frac{\sin{2\theta}}{2}) $$ $$=
>  \frac{a^2}{2}\left(\sin^{-1}{\frac{x}{a}}+\frac{{x}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a^2}\right) $$

Comment: You're forgetting $+C$ which is important here ;)

Comment: Note that $\arcsin t+\arccos t=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: +C, and once you account for that you will see that the to answers are the same.

Comment: Like Ian answered, both expressions are the same. But I would rather use the first substitution as the second has to consider the magnitude of $\cos\theta$ on the interval from $0$ to $\pi$. The second one is better as you don't have to consider the magnitude of $\sin\theta$ on the same interval.

Comment: Thanks. Now I realize that the constant is very important here. I hardly ever be aware of a constant $C$ in the indefinite integral...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\cos(\pi/2-x)=\sin(x)$ and vice versa. If you haven't seen this before, the geometric explanation is that the sine of one of the acute angles in a right triangle is the cosine of the other.

Therefore $-\cos^{-1}(x)$ and $\sin^{-1}(x)$ are the same up to a constant. Since indefinite integrals are only defined up to a constant (and the factor on the outside is a constant), your two solutions are consistent with each other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Oh I'm sorry, I shouldn't have asked this question. Anyone knows how to delete this post?

Comment: If you're allowed to, it is directly below the question, there would be buttons "share cite edit delete flag". I'm not sure you can at your rep level, though.

Comment: @ignite why shouldn't you have asked the question? Don't delete it.

Comment: I think this is some common pitfall in calculations of the indefinite integrals, but hope that this will be helpful for someone who might probably encounter the same problem. (Now I need more 17 seconds to accept the answer :))